# Responsive Post Thumbnails in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using `bootstrap` and want to apply the `img-responsive` and `img-circle` classes to a post thumbnail.

The problem is I don't know how to make the php code for the image thumbnail work inside an img tag.

Unless I can tag them I can't apply a class, and a div tag doesnt work.

I'm sure its simple but would appreciate a pointer.

code here - currently I have tried it in a div tag, which gets the image but doesnt apply the styles

```
<h4>Latest News</h4>
                <?php $counter = 3;
                $recentPosts = new WP_Query();
                $recentPosts->query('showposts=3');?>
                <?php while ($recentPosts->have_posts()) : $recentPosts->the_post(); ?>
                <div>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <div class="img-responsive img-circle"> <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> </div>
                    <p class="posttitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                    <p class="smallprint"><?php the_date(); ?></p>
                    <div><?php the_excerpt(10); ?></div>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: show us you current code and where exactly you're having problems

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved it with this

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'img-responsive img-circle')); ?>
```

also we can use this

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'thumbnail', array('class' => 'img-responsive img-circle')); ?>
```